# How to resolve the error: RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 16 elements not 32?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, batch-normalization

I am using a RE NET from https://github.com/iMED-Lab/RE-Net, and my input data is 448x448x128. When I run the Python program in Google Colab it gives the error RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 16 elements not 32.

The algorithm is here:

```
nonlinearity = partial(F.relu, inplace=True)



def downsample():
    return nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)


def deconv(in_channels, out_channels):
    return nn.ConvTranspose3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2)





def initialize_weights(*models):
    for model in models:
        for m in model.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv3d) or isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal(m.weight)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    m.bias.data.zero_()
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm3d):
                m.weight.data.fill_(1)
                m.bias.data.zero_()


class ResEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(ResEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels//2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(out_channels//2, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        self.conv1x1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = self.conv1x1(x)
        out = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(out)))
        out += residual
        out = self.relu(out)
        return out


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv3d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        return out







class RE_Net(nn.Module):
    # def __init__(self, classes, channels):
    def __init__(self):

        super(RE_Net, self).__init__()
        self.encoder1 = ResEncoder(1, 32)
        self.encoder2 = ResEncoder(32, 64)
        self.encoder3 = ResEncoder(64, 128)
        self.bridge = ResEncoder(128, 256)

        self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv3d(256, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv3d(128, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv3_3 = nn.Conv3d(64, 1, kernel_size=1)


        self.convTrans1 = nn.ConvTranspose3d(1, 1, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.convTrans2 = nn.ConvTranspose3d(1, 1, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.convTrans3 = nn.ConvTranspose3d(1, 1, kernel_size=2, stride=2)



        self.decoder3 = Decoder(256, 128)
        self.decoder2 = Decoder(128, 64)
        self.decoder1 = Decoder(64, 32)
        self.down = downsample()
        self.up3 = deconv(256, 128)
        self.up2 = deconv(128, 64)
        self.up1 = deconv(64, 32)
        self.final = nn.Conv3d(32, 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        initialize_weights(self)

    def forward(self, x):
        enc1 = self.encoder1(x)
        down1 = self.down(enc1)

        enc2 = self.encoder2(down1)
        down2 = self.down(enc2)

        con3_3 = self.conv3_3(enc2)
        convTrans3 = self.convTrans3(con3_3)
        x3 = -1 * (torch.sigmoid(convTrans3)) + 1
        x3 = x3.expand(-1, 32, -1, -1, -1).mul(enc1)
        x3 = x3 + enc1

        enc3 = self.encoder3(down2)
        down3 = self.down(enc3)

        con2_2 = self.conv2_2(enc3)
        convTrans2 = self.convTrans2(con2_2)
        x2 = -1 * (torch.sigmoid(convTrans2)) + 1
        x2 = x2.expand(-1, 64, -1, -1, -1).mul(enc2)
        x2 = x2 + enc2



        bridge = self.bridge(down3)

        conv1_1 = self.conv1_1(bridge)
        convTrans1 = self.convTrans1(conv1_1)


        x = -1 * (torch.sigmoid(convTrans1)) + 1
        x = x.expand(-1, 128, -1, -1, -1).mul(enc3)
        x = x + enc3

        up3 = self.up3(bridge)
        up3 = torch.cat((up3, x), dim=1)
        dec3 = self.decoder3(up3)

        up2 = self.up2(dec3)
        up2 = torch.cat((up2, x2), dim=1)
        dec2 = self.decoder2(up2)

        up1 = self.up1(dec2)
        up1 = torch.cat((up1, x3), dim=1)
        dec1 = self.decoder1(up1)

        final = self.final(dec1)
        final = F.sigmoid(final)
        return final
```

I have researched and found out the issue has something to do with batch normalization, and I have tried to adjust the numbers, but I do not know which line is causing the problem. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and read [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)

Comment: also add the modules that you have used. basically, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example